# How to make a composite key to be unique?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, uml, composite-key

I am making a database of students in one school.Here is what I have so far:
[image]

*If you don't like reading jump to the "In short" part*

The problem is that I'm not happy with this design. I want the combination of `grade`, `subgrade` and `id_class` to be unique and to serve as a primary key for the students table.
I can remove the `student_id` and make a composite key from the 3 but I don't want that either. Maybe I should make another table lets say `combination_id` where `grade`, `subgrade` and `id_class` are foreign keys and there is one extra column `comb_id` that serves as ID for the table. And all the columns will be Primary Keys. But the problem is that those 3 columns can still repeat because of that extra column (`comb_id`). For example I can have the same `grade`, `subgrade` and `class_id` but different `comb_id` which will make the row valid because of the composite key of the 4 columns of the table (`combination_id`).

In short I want `students_id` to remain the only primary key of the table but to be a foreign key to another table which is somehow unique combination of `grades`, `subgrade` and `class_id`.

If I was not clear enough ask in the comments below and thank you in advance.

PS *I'm sorry for the indescriptive title but I'm bad at naming*

**EDIT 1:**
To be more clear:
`grade` can be 1 to 12
`subgrade` can be a to j
`id_class` can be 1 to 30 and it is your number in class

So a student can be from 7b class and his number in class - 5

Comment: I don't understand, are all students in a class garaunteed to have different grades?

Comment: What will you do when students change class or, does this never happen?

Comment: What is wrong with a `student_id` column?

Comment: Are students in just 1 class, like a primary/junior/infant school?

Comment: @Jodrell I have edited my question to be more clear about those columns. And I want `student_id` to be a FK from another table which contains those 3 columns that serve as Composite key in it. If you still have questions ask

Comment: In your example, what happens next accademic year?  Will student 5 in class 7b move to class 8b?  (or some other class?)

Comment: Your title says: _"How to make a composite key to be unique?"_ All keys are unique, including composite keys. Please improve your title. Also, when you say: _"... make a composite key from the 3 but I don't want that either"_, **why** you don't want it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Don't mix the concepts of *unique keys* and *primary keys*. You can very well add a [unique key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_unique_constraint) spanning the three columns `grades`, `subgrade` and `class_id`. That way, no two rows [could have](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/constraint-primary-key.html) the same values for these three columns. As you write that you don't want to have these three as a composite primary key, I'm not sure whether a composite unique supplemental key would be any better. If not, you'll have to clarify when composite keys are acceptable.

To create a unique key, you can use the following SQL [statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html):

```
ALTER TABLE students ADD UNIQUE gsc (grades, subgrade, class_id);
```

The word `gsc` there is just a name I made up from the initials of the key columns; use whatever name you want, as it hardly matters unless you want to identify the key in some `EXPLAIN` output or similar.

Comment: thanks I'll try that and I probably confused people with the nameings of `grade`, `subgrade` and `id_class`, but in my country the education system is different.

Comment: OK I tried that but when I made all 3 columns `UNIQUE` I got an error for duplicate entries. I had many `grades` 3 but they had different `subgrades` so it treated them as separate `unique` keys. Also what is supplemental?

Comment: Don't make all thre columns unique by themselves, but together: `ALTER TABLE students ADD UNIQUE gsc (grades, subgrade, class_id)`. `gsc` is just a name, use whatever you like. Then duplicates only occur if all three are the same. I used the term *supplementary* as opposed to *primary*: A key defined using this command is not primary, but still unique.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not totally clear on why you want what you have described, but I would look at the model in the following way...

You have Students
- They are distinct entities, not a composite of other entities
- They have their own properties; name, date of birth, etc

You have classes
- These are groups of students
- Each accademic year the same "class" has different students in it
- They also have their own properties; grade, sub-grade, etc

You have an extra property in your model that I would not normally use
- If a class has 20 students, each of them is identified with a secondary id from 1 to 20

This would give *me* the following Dimension tables

```
Student                  Class                     Grade              SubGrade
-----------------------  ------------------------  -----------------  -----------------
id          INT PK       id           INT PK       id    INT PK       id    INT PK
first_name  VARCHAR(45)  name         VARCHAR(45)  name  VARCHAR(45)  name  VARCHAR(45)
last_name   VARCHAR(45)  grade_id     INT FK       desc  VARCHAR(45)  desc  VARCHAR(45)
etc, etc                 subgrade_id  INT FK       etc, etc           etc, etc
```

The `Class` table would have a unique constraint on `(grade_id, subgrade_id)` so that only one class could ever be `7b`.

Then you need to relate the students to their classes using a fact table...

```
Class_Membership
-----------------------
id               INT PK
student_id       INT FK
class_id         INT FK
academic_year    INT
```

If a student should only ever be in one class in any academic year, you would put a unique constraint on `(student_id, academic_year)`.

Alternatively, you could have the academic year in the `Class` table.  This would mean that you would have the same class repeated for every year, but that in some years class `7g` may not exist *(as there are less students that year, for example)*.

Equally, you could have students who move from `7b` to `7c` mid-year.  In which case the `Class_Membership` table could have a `start_date` field and possibly an `end_date` field.

None of that, however, directly creates the `id_class` field *(1-20 for a class with 20 students)*.  Personally I would not have such a field, the `id` field from the `Class_Membership` table can serve most of the same functionality, and probably additional functionality.  Where it *is* necessary, however, you could simply add it to the `Class_Membership` table...

```
Class_Membership
-----------------------
id               INT PK
student_id       INT FK
class_id         INT FK
academic_year    INT
class_member_id  INT
```

Then you could also have a unique constraint on `(academic_year, class_id, class_member_id)`.

There is quite a lot of flexibility here, depending on your exact real-world-model and your particular needs.  But hopefully this example is a good start for you; Dimension tables listing Entities, and a Fact table (or tables) relating these entities together and/or further describing the Entities.

Comment: As you queston the schema as it stands, I'll add my thoughts to it here. @Bosak, in my understanding the “subgrade” is only a letter to distinguish different classes in the same grade. So while grade and subgrade identify a class, a subgrade by itself isn't really an entity. You'll rarely be interested in “all classes with subgrade b”, and even less interested in storing common attributes for all those classes b, right? In that case, I'd drop the SubGrade table.

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table <TableName> add constraint <ConstraintName> unique(<col1>, <col2>)

Modified the answer due to syntax mistakes. Mentioned above is correct.
```